# New client connection to Tor private relay + obfs4proxy fails

Tags: configuration, torsocks, obfs4proxy

I encounter an issue trying to add another client to an already running tor+obfs4proxy setup. While the first client can connect with no issue to the server(outside Iran) the new client almost identical to the previous fails at the 10% bootstrap:

> May 31 11:55:53.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake
>   with directory server May 31 11:56:53.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable
>   to connect to 46.101.199.19:9443 ("general SOCKS server failure")

Suspecting something wrong in my serrver;I got 2x bridge relay addresses from tor:https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4
to yet stop at exactly the same step :(
How can I circumvent this? Can you please help?

Comment: Check the date and time on the connecting device is accurate to within 1 hour, or obfs4 will fail entirely.

Answer (score 1):

As earlier suspicion; it is the Iran's regime behind this and somehow they managed to block the handshake or initiation of any tor circuit even in the form of obfuscated V4. 
Honestly thought of the combination invincible but it fails. I did use the tor site relays in the configs and also the tor-browser all with the same symptom. That is how I am certain it should be the regime's DPI at work :(